# Code PHP on Wordpress does not work on PHP 8

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm moving my website to a new hosting, but the website doesn't start and an error appears. The error is due to a newer version of PHP, exactly from version 7.2 I am moving to version 8.

PHP code:

```
if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-wp.php')){
    $content_of_wp_class_file = file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-wp.php');
    $re = '/\$re \= \'\/\^\(\.\*\?\)\\\\\/uslugi\(\.\*\?\)\$\/\m\'\;/s';
    preg_match($re, $content_of_wp_class_file, $matches);
    if(count($matches) == 0){
        $replace = '$rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();';
        $replaceTo = '
            $rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();
            $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER[\'HTTPS\']) && $_SERVER[\'HTTPS\'] === \'on\' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $re = \'/^(.*?)\/uslugi(.*?)$/m\';
            preg_match($re, $actual_link, $match);
    
            if(!empty($match[2])){
                $cache31 = \'^uslugi\'.$match[2];
                $cache31 = rtrim($cache31, \'/\');
                $cache31 = $cache31.\'?$\';
                if(!empty($rewrite[$cache31])){
                    $re = \'/^(.*?)p=(\d+)/m\';
                    preg_match($re, $rewrite[$cache31], $matches);
                    if(isset($matches[2]) && (int) $matches[2] > 0){
                        $this->query_vars[\'p\'] = (int) $matches[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        ';

        $newContent = str_replace($replace, $replaceTo, $content_of_wp_class_file);
        file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/class-wp.php', $newContent);
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given in /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-content/themes/kendall-child/functions.php:424 Stack trace: #0 /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-settings.php(528): include() #1 /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-config.php(90): require_once('...') #2 /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-load.php(37): require_once('...') #3 /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...') #4 /wp-upiekszalnia/index.php(17): require('...') #5 {main} thrown in /wp-upiekszalnia/wp-content/themes/kendall-child/functions.php on line 424
```

424 line:

```
if(count($matches) == 0){
```

Thank you for your trouble.

Comment: The error says that line 424 in file fynctions.php can't count your $matches, because it is empty (null). When it is empty, there is nothing to count (no array) and PHP throws an error. The problem is that your $matches is empty when the PHP tries to count.

Comment: Well, not reproducible. You can also rewrite if condition as `if(preg_match($re, $content_of_wp_class_file, $matches) === 1){`

Comment: Your regex fails in PHP 8: https://3v4l.org/acDsY which causes `$matches` to be `null`. Make sure your error reporting level is `E_ALL` so you get all warnings and notices and not just errors.

Comment: The only reference about changes for regular expressions in PHP 8 I could find in a quick search was this: _"When passing invalid escape sequences they are no longer interpreted as literals. This behavior previously required the X modifier – which is now ignored."_ on the page [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.pcre). I don't really know regex enough to know what it actually means or what you need to change, but it might at least give you something to go on.